# Run shell script each time screen unlocked

Tags: javascript, android, bash, shell, sh

how to run Run shell script each time screen unlocked.

I use Magisk with /data/adb/service.d

For example, I have the following script:

```
#!/system/bin/sh

sleep 50
su -c CLASSPATH=/storage/emulated/0/DisplayToggle.dex app_process / DisplayToggle 0
```

I have a phone with a broken screen and I want to keep it always off

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: All I need is to run this script when unlocking the phone screen.  su -c CLASSPATH=/storage/emulated/0/DisplayToggle.dex app_process / DisplayToggle 0